# How to calculate distinct minutes in a time period

Tags: javascript, php, datetime, time, date-arithmetic

Not sure if distinct is the right word.

Here is a made up scenario to explain what I would like to get.

Say there are two Hair Salons.

Salon A has 2 employees.
Salon B has 1 employee.

Say I want to calculate how many minutes of activity there are for a salon in a given hour.

If Salon A has the following hair appointments:

- Customer A: Started at 0 minutes and ended at 10 minutes (10 min hair cut)
- Customer B: Started at 2 minutes and ended at 12 minutes (10 min hair cut)

And Salon B has the following hair appointments:

- Customer C: started at 0 minutes and ended at 10 minutes (10 min hair cut)
- Customer D: started at 10 minutes and ended at 20 minutes (10 min hair cut)

In this scenario I want to see:

- Salon A - 12 Minutes of activity
- Salon B - 20 Minutes of activity

I would then be able to say that if Customer E went to Salon A they would be waiting about 6 minutes for every person ahead of them in the queue to get a hair cut but if they went to Salon B they would be waiting about 10 minutes for every customer ahead of them. (Activity divided by customers completed). I need a way to calculate this without relying on the number of staff at a salon.

One way I can think of is to have an array and fill it with unique minutes. e.g.
irrate over the bookings and add each minute to the array, subsequent bookings would just write over the existing minutes that have already been filled then I would have an array with 12 items (minutes) for Salon A and an array of 20 items (minutes) for Salon B. I believe this would work but wanted to know if there is a better/more practical way of doing this?

I don't mind what language just wanted to see the logic.

Comment: I wrote a set of classes to deal with a similar situation. It may help. https://github.com/vascowhite/Time

Comment: You calculation is not correct. For A, average is 5 minutes, because every 10 minutes, 2 customer will finish their appointment. The example of 12 minutes misleads you.

Comment: @LeoDeng: the OP is not talking about average, he is talking about how much time does salon work. And SalonA has 12min of activity.

Comment: @Glavić I was referring to this sentence he said: **they would be waiting about 6 minutes for every person ahead of them in the queue to get a hair**.

Answer (score 0):

A simple attempt here, in JavaScript.

Say, 10 minutes for every customer, that's a constant. So for Salon B, that's super easy: there's only 1 barber, activity time is **10 * number of customers**.

Now for Salon A, say `app` is an array that stores the starting point of every appointment. For example:

```
var app = [0, 2, 10, 13, 20, 32]
```

It means there are 6 customers (potentially like this: barber A has 0-10, 10-20, 20-30, 32-42, barber B has 2-12, 13-23, poor barber A).

And we have an arry `timeline`. Let's loop through `app`:

```
var timeline = [];
for(var i = 0; i < app.length; i++) {
    for(var j = app[i]; j < app[i] + 10; j++) {
        timeline[j] = 1;
    }
}
```

Now, `timeline` explicitly recorded every active minute, also contains holes of inactive. `1` for active, `undefined` for inactive.

Then we reduce `timeline`, which will skip `undefined` automatically:

```
var activity = timeline.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
});
activity; // 40
```

40. You got it!

---

Edit: this is just one solition, I'm sure there are others, which may perform better than this one :)